# Authenticate to an Azure webapp through a second app registration using an Azure user token?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

**Working scenario**

I have an Azure web application (https://www.contoso.com) to which I want to authenticate against and perform web call on.

I want to authenticate myself using `Connect-AzAccount` and make calls to it using my own identity.

I use the following code with success to obtain a valid token and call the application.

```
#Authenticate as myself or a sevice principal 
Connect-AzAccount -Tenant 'a736bac3-c259-450f-90a4-f7d5bd7c4c78'

# App registration ID for Contoso
$ResourceUri = '24114488-8c26-4e87-8f71-90de62f5a8aa'
$Context = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile.DefaultContext
$token = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, $ResourceUri).AccessToken
$Headers = @{Headers = @{Authorization = "Bearer $token" } }
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -uri 'https://Contoso.com/module/Something' @Headers
```

That being said, the application itself does not implement forced user & groups assignment.
Instead, everybody can connect to it (by design).

**The problematic**

The solution presented above requires me to add Powershell Azure (1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2) in the list of **Authorized client application** to enable this scenario. By doing this operation, anybody in my directory can now technically make calls to the website, which is not desired.

[image: Authorized client application]

**Desired Scenario**

Because user assignment is not enforced, I removed the **Powershell Azure** client from the main app and instead created a second App Registration for which I authorized the PS AZ client and added an **API permission** so it had access to the main App. The idea is that I can require user assignement for the second app registration and therefore limit the user that can make these kind of calls.

Initial (working) flow:

- Connect-AzAccount authenticate the user
- Code sample above is ran to obtain the token and call the app.

Desired flow

- Connect-AzAccount authenticate the user
- User connect through the client app registraion (new app) that has api permission to the main app.
- User make calls to the main app.

Now, if I try to use my initial code sample with the Application Id of the second registration acting as a client ID, I get the following error

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"code":401,"message":"IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: '[PII is hidden]'. Did not 
match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: '[PII is hidden]' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: '[PII is hidden]'."}
At line:1 char:12
+ $result2 = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -uri 'https://Contoso.com/so...
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebExcept  
   ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

I believe that this is because I am obtaining a token for the second app registration and trying to call the main app URL, which is not authorized through the token.

A "working" alternative to this problem would be to connect using **Client_credentials** as **grant_type** such as this:

```
function get-Bearer([string]$TenantID, [string]$ClientID, [string]$ClientSecret) {
    $TokenEndpoint = "https://login.windows.net/{0}/oauth2/token" -f $TenantID 


    $Body = @{
        'resource'      = '24114488-8c26-4e87-8f71-90de62f5a8aa'
        'client_id'     = $ClientID
        'grant_type'    = 'client_credentials'
        'client_secret' = $ClientSecret
    }

    $params = @{
        ContentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        Headers     = @{'accept' = 'application/json' }
        Body        = $Body
        Method      = 'Post'
        URI         = $TokenEndpoint
    }

    $token = Invoke-RestMethod @params

    Return "Bearer " + ($token.access_token).ToString()
}
```

If I do that, even though I can make calls to the main app. again but it is connected with the actual client app. and not using the user identity obtained through `Connect-AzAccount` (for which tokens can be generated through the initial sample)

I was also able to make it work with a **password** grant_type but this is not making use of my bearer token and is also invalidated by MFA enabled users.

All insights are welcome.

**References**

[Microsoft Identity platform documentation - v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow)
(digging around the application flow to try and get something working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally succeeded in my attempt.

In case my initial question was confusing, I "simply" wanted to connect as myself on **Web API B** using an intermediary **Web API A**

The reason was that I could not implement control access on **Web API  B** (it is a requirement that it is available for all users of the tenant) and I also could not add Powershell client ID to **Web API B** directly as this would have allowed everyone to obtain a token and make call to **Web API B** using Powershell.

Therefore, I needed the intermediary **Web API A** to allow Powershell client ID and provide a controlled / limited user access to **Web API B**

There is a flow in the [Microsoft identity platform and Oauth 2.0 called On-Behal-Of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow) which allow exactly that scenario.

[image: OAuth 2.0 On-Behalf-Of flow]

**Prerequisites**

App Registration for Web API B

- API Permission: Delegated permission to User.Read (Graph API)
- Expose an API: add a **User_Impersonation** scope and the Application ID of **Web API A** in the authorized client ID

App Registration for Web API A

- In **Api Permissions**, add the **User_Impersonation** scope of **Web API B**

From there, the following code will get you connected

```
Connect-AzAccount -TenantId '584e32bc-214f-4046-89e5-79b7bac9ae75'

$Params = @{
    ClientId     = '6788d279-fb83-4962-b371-445479875e0e'
    ClientSecret = '16cc0f3d88cb4dd189fe6bf8e845982d'
    resourceId   = 'aeefa559-cb1c-41eb-ac5d-0bcb0bc01eaf'
    Scope        = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read+offline_access'
}

function Get-AzCustomTokenOnBehalOf {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        $ClientId, 
        $ClientSecret,
        #Application ID of the target resource
        $ResourceId,
        $Scope 
    )
    
    # Get Token For WebApp A $TenantId
    $Context = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile.DefaultContext
    $IntermediaryToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, $ClientId).AccessToken
    $TokenUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$($Context.Tenant.Id)/oauth2/token" 
    
    $FinalToken = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $TokenUri -Method Post -Body @{
        grant_type          = 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer'
        resource            = $ResourceId
        client_id           = $ClientId
        client_secret       = $ClientSecret
        assertion           = $IntermediaryToken
        scope               = $Scope
        requested_token_use = 'on_behalf_of'
    }

    return $FinalToken
}

$Token = Get-AzCustomTokenOnBehalOf @Params
$Headers = @{Headers = @{Authorization = "bearer $($Token.access_token)" } }

$MYsite = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -uri 'https://SomeWebsite.com/' @Headers
```

**Additional considerations**
This scenario do require a client secret (This is the one I demonstratedO  or a client certificate in order to work.

It is also subject to some limitations defined in the reference documentation and might not be suitable to all scenarios.

References:

[Microsoft identity platform and OAuth 2.0 On-Behalf-Of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow)

Answer (score 1):

Application `app ids`, not `object ids`, should be used as resources identifiers. Keep getting tokens using the first application (`24114488-8c26-4e87-8f71-90de62f5a8aa`) as resource/audience (using its [application id uri](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-modify-supported-accounts#change-the-application-registration-to-support-different-accounts)) and the second application as client. `Connect-Az` will be out of the equation.

```
#Install the ADAL.PS package if it's not installed.
if(!(Get-Package adal.ps)) { Install-Package -Name adal.ps }

$authority = "https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize"
#this is the security and compliance center endpoint
$resourceUrl = "{first application id uri}"
#replace <redirect-uri>, with the Redirect URI from your Azure AD application registration.
$clientId = "{second application app id}"
$redirectUri = "<redirect-uri>"

$response = Get-ADALToken -Resource $resourceUrl -ClientId $clientId -RedirectUri $redirectUri -Authority $authority -PromptBehavior:Always
$response.AccessToken | clip
```

Comment: What I really want to achieve is to authenticate User A to Resource as User A. Kind of a double Hop scenario. UserA -> Client -> Resource (where User A is connected). To put it in other words, Client is making the connection to Resource on behalf of User A. Any call to Resource is auditable as a call made by User A.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the mixup with Object ID in my question. I really meant App Id (I edited my question accordingly.